# Fastest way to sum the values of the pixels above a threshold in an image with Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to find to the best method to retrieve the sum of the pixels **value** that are bigger than a certain threshold. For example, if my threshold is 253, and I got 10 pixels that are 254, and another 10 that are 255, I expect to get `10*254 + 10*255 = 5090` - sort of total intensity of the pixels that are over the threshold.

I found a way to do so with `np.histogram`:

```
import cv2, time
import numpy as np
threshold = 1
deltaImg = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
t0=time.time()
histogram = np.histogram(deltaImg,256-threshold,[threshold,256])
histoSum = sum(histogram[0]*histogram[1][:-1])
print(histoSum)
print("time = %.2f ms" % ((time.time()-t0)*1000))
```

This works and I get the sum of the pixels **valus** that were bigger than the selected threshold.
However, I am not sure this is the best/fastest way to go. Obviously, the bigger the threshold is, the faster the action will take.

Does any one has an idea how can I get the right result but with a faster algorithm?

Comment: Are you sure that your proposed approach works? If I compute it on say `np.array([250, 1, 255])` I get some `505.0` while I should really be getting `255` with threshold `253`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While OP's approach is fundamentally inaccurate, the underlying idea can still be use to craft an approach that is valid for integer arrays (such as grayscale images):

```
def sum_gt_hist(arr, threshold):
    values = np.arange(threshold, np.max(arr) + 1)
    hist, edges = np.histogram(arr, values + 0.5)
    return sum(values[1:] * hist)
```

This is however non-ideal because it is more complex than it should be (`np.histogram()` is a relatively complex function which computes much more intermediate information than needed) and would only work for integer values.

A simpler and still pure NumPy approach was proposed in [@sehan2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69752607/5218354):

```
import numpy as np


def sum_gt_np(arr, threshold):
    return np.sum(arr[arr > threshold])
```

While the above would be the preferred NumPy-only solution, much faster execution (and memory efficiency) can be obtained with a simple Numba-based solution:

```
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def sum_gt_nb(arr, threshold):
    arr = arr.ravel()
    result = 0
    for x in arr:
        if x > threshold:
            result += x
    return result
```

---

Benchmarking the above with a random 100x100 array representing an image, one would get:

```
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 100))  # generate a random image
threshold = 253  # set a threshold

funcs = sum_gt_hist, sum_gt_np, sum_gt_nb
for func in funcs:
    print(f"{func.__name__:16s}", end='  ')
    print(func(arr, threshold), end='  ')
    %timeit func(arr, threshold)

# sum_gt_hist       22397  355 µs ± 8.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# sum_gt_np         22397  10.1 µs ± 438 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# sum_gt_nb         22397  1.19 µs ± 33.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

This indicates that `sum_gt_nb()` is largely faster than `sum_gt_np()` which in turn is largely faster than `sum_gt_hist()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np
image = np.random.randint(0,256,(10,10))
threshold = 1
res = np.sum(image[image > threshold])
```

This operation:

```
%%timeit
res = np.sum(image[image >=threshold])
```

takes `5.43 µs ± 137 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the fastest, but it is pretty simple. In Python/OpenCV, threshold to zero only pixels below the threshold keeping the values above threshold as the original values. Then simply count the values that are not zero.

I created a simple ramp image that is 100 pixels wide and goes from 255 at the top down to 0 at the bottom in 1 gray level increments.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('ramp.png')
print(img.shape)

# convert img to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold to zero below threshold, but keep values above threshold
# note: to count all values of 254 and 255, use threshold at 253
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 253, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)[1]

# sum pixel values
# zero values don't contribute to sum
sum1 = np.sum(thresh)
print("actual count:", sum1)

# compute the expected count
sum2 = 100*254+100*255
print("computed count:", sum2)

# show results
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Results:

```
actual count: 50900
computed count: 50900
```

Comment: why not just `np.sum(thresh)` over `np.sum(thresh[thresh != 0])`? It is definitely simpler and should be faster as well. Also I'd avoid using a built-in name like `sum` as a variable.

Comment: `@norok2`  Good points. Still learning Python/OpenCV/Numpy. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: `@norok2` Thanks again. I have updated my answer to reflect your comments.